# How to generate a serial number based on a selected field value?

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I have a content type in which there is an entity reference. All content of it is set to unpublished by default and upon creation a rule is run to assign an organic group based on the selected reference.

Now, upon publication of the content I want to have an incremental number assigned to a node based on the entity reference it contains. 
For example:

> Node1     ref:abc    c:1
>   Node2     ref:def    c:1
>   Node3     ref:abc    c:2
>   Node4     ref:abc    c:3
>   Node5     ref:def    c:2

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check [this post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763223/drupal-7-how-to-trigger-hook-the-node-publish-event) for info about Revisioning module's added hooks for when a node gets published, revised or reverted.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to the code snippet here https://www.drupal.org/node/2058739 as an action rule.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I'd recommend answering your own question with your code snippet included (as opposed to a link) for others, this will also close the question. If my first comment was helpful feel free to +1 :)

Comment: Suggestion: transform your comment in a real answer (include that link, and also a copy of the relevant part of it) ...